# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>. in gatsby js project

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-bootstrap

So I'm using gatsby JS with react-bootstrap and Im unclear about how to use Gatsby's native routing while using react-bootstrap which appears to use react-router... I'm nesting Gatsby's `<Link></Link>` inside react-bootstrap's `<Nav.Link href="#stuff"><Nav.Link>` and it works, but it seems to be somehow messing with the DOM because I open up the console and I'm getting this error `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.` Heres my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../pages/styles.scss';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

const CamcoNavbar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link><Link to="/about/">About</Link></Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link><Link to="/companies/">Companies</Link></Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link><Link to="/sustainability/">Sustainability</Link></Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link><Link to="/riseabove/">Rise Above</Link></Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link><Link to="/team/">Our Team</Link></Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link><Link to="/contact/">Contact</Link></Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
            Dank memes
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

export default CamcoNavbar
```

How should I go about routing using both gatsby and react-bootstrap??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing Nav.Link to Nav.Item (or import NavItem from react-bootstrap), that will give you the styling of the nav items, but it isn't a type of link so it won't mess with you gatsby Link. Currently you are putting one router link inside of another, so when you click the gatsby app doesn't know what to do because you're telling it to go to two different places even if you haven't defined an href in your Nav.Link component.